# Svelte web app doesn't load CSS styles on page refresh from a route page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a website that I recently converted from React to Svelte. After deploying the Svelte version of the website to production I noticed an issue where when on any page except home, hitting refresh then reloads the page without any of the CSS styles. Note that the CSS loads fine and everything renders perfectly on initial load, its not until you refresh the page that the CSS fails to load.

Try it out for yourself here at https://www.tswmaps.com. Click any link then reload the page to see what I'm talking about. The page reloads without any of the previous CSS styles, and it even looks like it is taking you back to the home page without style. Below is one of the console errors observed:

```
The stylesheet https://tswmaps.com/game/_app/immutable/assets/0.7438fdf9.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
```

The strange thing is that this is not an issue on the localhost when running `npm run dev`.

Note: The project is using the Svelte static adapter and the site is hosted on HostGator. Feel free to view the project here: https://github.com/joshcv2112/tswmaps_svelte

When I deployed the project to prod I ran `npm run build`, then used FTP to transfer all contents of the build folder to the server. I'm really stumped as to how the website is having issues on reload when none of this is an issue locally.

Comment: Sounds like just a host issue if it does not serve with the correct content type.

Comment: Not sure how to change that in the server... I can't imagine why its serving CSS incorrectly, my previous version of the website (ReactJS) had no issue serving CSS.

Comment: something is wrong with your server setup, more specifically the redirects.  When you go to "World" map and the hit refresh the site does reload, just on the wrong page (the home one).  This is an indication that somehow files are being redirected. Note that that is beyond Svelte's scope as it is potentially different for each host.